# Convert non-RAID disk with data into RAID 1 disk (hardware controller)

Tags: hardware, raid, conversion, raid1

I moved away from software RAID due to all the hassle it brings. After an OS reinstall, I am left with only one drive. I ordered a hardware RAID controller today, and when the controller arrives, I'd like to plug in the identical drives into the RAID controller and set up RAID 1 WITHOUT losing any data or needing to reinstall the OS (Debian Jessie x86_64).

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1              8:1    0   953M  0 part /boot
├─sda2              8:2    0  29.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3              8:3    0 900.8G  0 part
  ├─vgmain-lvroot 254:0    0 621.4G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vgmain-lvmail 254:1    0  93.1G  0 lvm  /var/vmail
  ├─vgmain-lvhome 254:2    0  93.1G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─vgmain-lvtmp  254:3    0  18.6G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─vgmain-lvvar  254:4    0  74.5G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                 8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
```

Can I do this somehow by `dd`ing the existing data to the clean drive while having it plugged into the RAID controller and set up as RAID 1? To clarify, let's say sda is the drive with my data, sdb is the drive which is not in use.

- Plug sda into the mobo sata controller
- Plug sdb into the RAID controller
- Define sdb as RAID 1 drive
- Boot from liveCD and `dd` contents of sda → sdb
- Plug sda into RAID controller, define as RAID1
- RAID controller syncs the drives, (copies over sdb to sda) (?)
- Boot without problems?

Will `dd` copy the drive in a way that mbr/partitions/etc. are preserved? Am I thinking in a completely stupid way of doing this?

I contacted the RAID controller manufacturer and asked if it has some kind of utility to convert a drive into 2 drives in RAID1, but they said no. If it's relevant in any way, the specific controller is a HighPoint RocketRAID 620 PCI-Express 2.0 x1 SATA III RAID card.

Comment: If you think software raid is a hassle, just wait until you get to experience the "joy" of hardware raid.

Comment: @cas what do you mean? A HW RAID cannot be broken by the OS in a way a software RAID can easily be misconfigured, and upon reboot the system will fail to load (forcing me to drive 80km and fixing the server on spot instead of ssh'ing as I always do).

Comment: Yes, it can (and when it does, it'll be much harder to fix).  It can also break in other fun and exciting ways - you'll absolutely love discovering that when your HW RAID controller dies, you can't just replace it with any other controller, often not even one from the same manufacturer....and the model you need hasn't been made for years.  There's only one good reason to use HW RAID - and that's so you can have non-volatile write-cache for RAID5 or RAID6.  If R5/R6 is not a requirement, HW RAID is a waste of money.   And if you need the capacity of R5/R6, you're still better off with ZFS.

Comment: IMO, the simplest and best thing for you to do is partition sbd exactly the same as sda, make sdb1 a degraded RAID1 (with either LVM or mdadm), rsync `/boot` to it, unmount /boot, add sda1 to the RAID1, and remount it as /boot.  **Don't forget to run `update-grub`**.  and `grub-install /dev/sdb` to install the grub boot-loader in the 2nd drive's MBR.  sdb2 could be a second swap partition (don't bother with RAID0 for swap, linux already stripes swap devices that have the same priority).  And add sdb3 as a mirror (i.e. RAID1) to the existing LVM volume group (currently consisting of only sda3).

Comment: Hardware RAID is a very problematic solution. Apart from what @cas has said, you may find that not all controllers are created equal and some of them are really some hard/soft hybrid. There is nothing that prevents you from creating a softraid for all your partitions and install grub on both of the disks. Just avoid using UUIDs for partition references in grub and fstab. This way, if your #1 disk fails, it will boot from the #2 and it will reassemble the soft RAID1 set with just the second disk.

Comment: @Panos yes, that's exactly how I manage my current servers. RAID1 with LVM on top of them, and LVM is able to scan the disks, I have only logical names in fstab, And grub installed on all RAID1 members. But thanks anyway five years from asking the question :D

Comment: You are right about the resurrection and it is the second time that I do the same mistake. For some crazy reason, this question was 2nd or 3rd in my feed and I just didn't check the date. I will now turn back to shame myself :P

Comment: @Panos no answer was accepted so it's perfectly acceptable to resurrect the question. (And actually, even if there was an accepted answer, if you can write a better one please do so.)

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is correct. Your terminology could use small detail work though.

You want to declare the second,new disk to be a member of a new *degraded* RAID1 array.

Then boot with a liveCD, `dd` the Data over, and then declare the first,older disk to be a *mirror* of the above array.

Depending on how exactly GRUB locates the RootFS, you may need to edit your GRUB config, or run `update-grub`.

One thing to check: The RAID-Header may be on-disk, so maybe your RAID will be slightly smaller than the underlying physical drives

Comment: Don't use `dd` for cloning disks, that's one of the slowest, least flexible way of doing it (for example, it will waste time copying unused disk space).  Use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).   or DIY with `rsync`.

Comment: @cas: Clonezilla uses `partimage`, which in turn needs to understand each specific filesystem block device layout. And rsync only copies filesystem content as files. Depending on your use-case, one/both of these may make you have to use `dd`.

Comment: Both of those facts are **features** not problems, and are exactly why I recommended using clonezilla or rsync.  bit-for-bit copies of the OS disk may be required for primitive OSes like Windows, but not for Linux.  Linux does not care where on the disk any file is, so a file copy will work without a problem.  In fact, a file copy will automatically and completely defrag the files as it copies them to the target fs.

Comment: @cas : You and I, and many others here, know that. But a new user might not. That new user will then wonder, why part-image wont efficiently transfer only the used space of -say- an encrypted blockdevice, or why the rsync-copy of a Windows-FS fails to boot. So `dd` in this case is the slower, but "safer" (=less to explain/understand) method

Comment: The OP was asking about linux filesystems, there was no mention of windows.  a novice user is unlikely to even notice the issue with an encrypted device, and an experienced user will understand why.    There's also no good reason to point novices at tools like `dd` (which are **easy** to make data-destroying mistakes with) rather than superior, safer tools like Clonezilla.  or rsync (or `cp -af` or `tar ... | tar ...`)

Comment: @cas does your clonezilla solution preserve the mbr and partitioning of the disk?

Comment: It can. By default it does. Clonezilla is also capable of auto-resizing partitions/disks when cloned to a larger disk. In this case, it would preserve the partitions etc, but it doesn't matter much. What's important is the data, not the exact partition layout.  and yes, CZ does understand and work with LVM.  BTW, did you realise that LVM can do RAID1 by itself, without mdadm?

Comment: @cas that is good info. I will return to report when the RAID controller arrives + I have time to upgrade the server.

Comment: rsync is not a disk duplication tool. Nor is cp or tar. The partition table, the boot record and the UUIDs will need to be preserved in order for the disk to be able to boot. Clonezilla will also turn to some block-by-block copying method in case of encrypted drives. DD is the best tool if one wants to duplicate a disk.